# How to create a carousel slider inside BottomSheet with expand/collapse animations like in the reddit Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, bottom-sheet, android-viewpager2

I wanted to create a pages slider (preferably with ViewPager2 not ViewPager) which would be inside a bottom sheet. When expanded the visible page would grow to fill the screen and when collapsed it would return to normal showing one visible page with a small part of the left & right pages visible from the sides. All this with a smooth animation.
My final implementation should be like in the sub-reddit slider in the Reddit Android app. Like in the video:

[image: screen recording of Reddit app]

Can you guide me on how to achieve this animation and where to start?